# Paging URL rewriting not working in php using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am using this rule in .htaccess :-

```
RewriteRule ^online-sale on-sale.php
RewriteRule ^online-sale/page-([0-9]+)$ on-sales.php?page=$1
```

First rule is working fine. for eg. if i call http://www.sitename/online-sale than page is opening successfully. When i am calling http://www.sitename/online-sale/page-2 than page is opening fine, but I can't access `$_REQUEST["page"]` value on this page.

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem? Is it possible or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on-sale**s** < typo in second rule? Also your first rule should end with a `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use anchor `$` in first rule to avoid matching for paging URL as well:

```
RewriteRule ^online-sale/?$ on-sale.php [L]
RewriteRule ^online-sale/page-([0-9]+)/?$ on-sale.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It is also advisable to use `L` and `QSA` flags.

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.